# Postgres knex query joining columns

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js

I have a Postgres DB that stores data in a table that has the following columns "date | uid | id | value | data".

Using [knex](http://knexjs.org/) on a node.js server I currently get from this query:

```
data = await db(tableName).select(["date", "uid", "id", "value", "value as market_cap", "data"]).whereIn("id", ["index", "market_cap", "market"]);
```

the following result:

```
"data": [
{
  "date": "2020-11-07T21:43:11.709Z",
  "uid": "nmvdqy0kh87sd8a",
  "id": "index",
  "value": "999.9999999999999",
  "market_cap": "999.9999999999999",
  "data": null
},
{
  "date": "2020-11-07T21:43:11.709Z",
  "uid": "nmvdqy0kh87sd8b",
  "id": "market_cap",
  "value": "10125616413",
  "market_cap": "10125616413",
  "data": null
},
{
  "date": "2020-11-07T21:43:11.709Z",
  "uid": "nmvdqy0kh87sd8c",
  "id": "market",
  "value": null,
  "market_cap": null,
  "data": {
    "1": [],
    "2": []
  }
},
...
```

];

The date pairs are all exactly the same. Data stored under id "market_cap" is actually stored as "value"  and data stored under id "market" is actually stored as "data".

Now, what I actually need is:

```
"data": [
{
  "date": "2020-11-07T21:43:11.709Z",
  "value": "999.9999999999999",
  "market_cap": "10125616413",
  "data": {
    "1": [],
    "2": []
  }
},
...
```

];

Is there a way to obtain this data structure directly from the database instead of transforming the data on the server? Bonus points it you provide the knex query / SQL query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a self-join on `date` and selecting on the rows with certain IDs. Left join ensures a result for each date even if they're missing a data type.

```
select mv."date", mv.value, mc.value as market_cap, md.data
from market_snapshots mv
left join market_snapshots mc on mv."date" = mc."date" and mc.id = 'market_cap'
left join market_snapshots md on mv."date" = md."date" and md.id = 'market'
where mv.id = 'index';
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8566cf32e2dd1c598d2c2da5331728e).

In Knex it would be something like...

```
knex.select(['mv.date', 'mv.value', 'mc.value as market_cap', 'md.data'])
  .from({ mv: 'market_snapshots' })
  .leftJoin({ mc: 'market_snapshots' }, function() {
    this.on('mv.date', '=', 'mc.date').andOn(knex.raw('mc.id = ?', 'market_cap'))
  })
  .leftJoin({ md: 'market_snapshots' }, function() {
    this.on('mv.date', '=', 'md.date').andOn(knex.raw('md.id = ?', 'market'))
  })
  .where('mv.id', 'index')
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it working in the sandbox based on what you did like so: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=18cdc77840b165e56caf1582fa67ecd2)

However knex throws an error claiming id "market_cap" column does not exist. There's also a missing closing "}" in the query :-)

Comment: @pspray I see, there's no actual market_cap column. It's virtual. I will fix the answer. In the future, be sure to provide your schema. The less people need to infer, the better answers you'll get.

Comment: Thanks, will do! I think it's a knex issue. The query resolves to (select "mv"."date", "mv"."value", "mc"."value" as "market_cap", "md"."data" from "market_snapshots" as "mv" left join "market_snapshots" as "mc" on "mv"."date" = "mc"."date" and "mc"."id" = "market_cap" left join "market_snapshots" as "md" on "mv"."date" = "md"."date" and "md"."id" = "market" where "mv"."id" = "index"). It doesn't work with double quotes. Not sure how to get around this with knex yet...

Comment: @pspray Got it. Knex will assume join on clauses are about columns. [`knex.raw`](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-raw) lets us specify literals.